# How can I find a bound for $\frac{n}{1} +\cdots+ \frac{n}{n}$ given $n< 10^{18}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Could you help me find a bound for 
>   $$\frac{n}{1} +\cdots+ \frac{n}{n}
> $$
>    given $n< 10^{18}$?

If there isn't any mathematical formula, algorithms will help too :)

Comment: @Chris: how does your described sum come up with the term $n\over 3$ if $(n,3)=1$?

Comment: @abiessu Ah, that's my mistake. I misread.

Comment: @Chris is there a closed form for the $n$th harmonic number?

Comment: Tip: it is the same to find $n\,\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$

Comment: There is no closed form for the $n$th harmonic number, by the way.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{n=1}^{10^{18}}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac nk$?

Comment: The question is unclear: $10^{18}$ is the bound for the *sum* or $n$?

Comment: I have edited your question to make it clear. If that is not what you meant, please roll it back.

Comment: @Jack Thanks for doing that. I actually meant n could be any natural number from 1 to 10^18 .

Answer (score 10):

Using the asymtopic behaviour of the harmonic series, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
n \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i}= n \left(\ln n +\gamma+ \frac{1}{2n} + o(\frac{1}{n^2})\right)
\end{eqnarray*}
Which gives a value of about $\color{red}{4.1 \times 10^{19}}$.

Comment: Thanks. Actually the current solution is something like this (just someone told me in moments ago) .
But I was searching for the problem where I found this: http://www.claymath.org/millennium-problems/riemann-hypothesis

Comment: Is there anything we can do by Riemann Zeta function for ζ(1) ?

Comment: The crucial thing was to recognise the harmonic series $H_n = \sum_{i}^{n} \frac{1}{i}$ then the wikipedia ref give by Daniel Cunha (above) will do. Yeah this is essentially the description of the singularity of the $\zeta$ function at $1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{n}{i}=n \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i}=n H_n  $$ If you have a look to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0510585.pdf) you will find sharp bounds for the harmonic numbers and, in particular, equation $(6)$
$$\frac{1}{2 n+\frac{1}{1-\gamma }-2} \leq H_n-\log(n)-\gamma \lt\frac{1}{2 n+\frac 13}$$ giving 
$$n \left(\frac{1}{2 n+\frac{1}{1-\gamma }-2}+\log (n)+\gamma \right)\leq nH_n \lt n \left(\frac{1}{2 n+\frac{1}{3}}+\log (n)+\gamma \right)$$

The difference of the bounds is $$\Delta=\frac{(4-7 \gamma ) n}{(2 \gamma  (n-1)-2 n+1) (6 n+1)}$$ and, for $n=10^{18}$, $\Delta\approx 8.0\times 10^{-21}$ (quite small !).

So, for  $n=10^{18}$, the summation is $\approx 4.202375\times 10^{19}$ .

If fact, setting $n=10^k$, you should notice that $\Delta_k\approx  8.0\times 10^{-(k+3)}$ for any value of $k$.

This gives you, I hope, not only very sharp bounds but also very accurate values.

**Edit**

In this [more recent paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.3856.pdf), they give 
$$-\frac{1}{12 n^2+\frac{2 (7-12 \gamma )}{2 \gamma -1}}\leq H_n-\log(n)-\frac 1{2n} <-\frac{1}{12 n^2+\frac{6}{5}}$$ which, for $nH_n$ makes the difference of the bounds to be $$\Delta=\frac{(33 \gamma -19) n}{3 \left(10 n^2+1\right) \left(-6 n^2+12 \gamma 
   \left(n^2-1\right)+7\right)}$$ and, for $n=10^{18}$, $\Delta\approx 1.7\times 10^{-57}$.

Setting again $n=10^k$, you should notice that $\Delta_k\approx  1.7\times 10^{-3(k+3)}$ for any value of $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Following is a very simple calculation.

For all $n>1$, $$\dfrac{n}{1} +\cdots+ \dfrac{n}{n}=n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}\le n\int_{1}^n\frac{1}{x}~dx=n\ln n.$$

Since $n<10^{18}$, we have that

$$\dfrac{n}{1} +\cdots+ \dfrac{n}{n}<10^{18}\ln (10^{18})\approx 4.1\times 10^{19}.$$